# How to get endpoint credentials for VSTS task

Tags: node.js, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have the following VSTS task and input:

```
 {
      "name": "ConnectedServiceName",
      "type": "connectedService:Azure",
      "label": "Azure Subscription",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "required": true,
      "helpMarkDown": "Select the Azure subscription for the deployment. Only the supported Azure service connections are displayed and they are of the authentication type of Credentials or Service Principals."
    },
```

and task.js

```
var path = require('path');
var tl = require('vso-task-lib');

var echo = new tl.ToolRunner(tl.which('KeyVaultSecretManager.exe', true));
var auth = tl.getEndpointAuthorization(tl.getInput("ConnectedServiceName", true));

echo.arg(tl.getEndpointUrl(tl.getInput("ConnectedServiceName", true)) + " " + (typeof auth.parameters.servicePrincipalId) + " " + auth.parameters.servicePrincipalId + " " + auth.parameters.servicePrincipalKey + " " + JSON.stringify(auth));

echo.exec({ failOnStdErr: false })
.then(function (code) {
    tl.exit(code);
})
.fail(function (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    tl.debug('taskRunner fail');
    tl.exit(1);
})
```

and I am wondering how do I get the actual values and not just `*******` as the output indicate:

```
C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\TestKeyVaultSecretManager\0.1.10\KeyVaultSecretManager.exe https://management.core.windows.net/ string ******** ******** {parameters:{ servicePrincipalId: ********, servicePrincipalKey: ********, tenantId: ********}, scheme: ServicePrincipal}
Testing KeyVault https://management.core.windows.net/ string ******** ******** {parameters:{ servicePrincipalId: ********, servicePrincipalKey: ********, tenantId: ********}, scheme: ServicePrincipal}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that they actually implemented this in a nice way and i got fooled.

The sensitive data are hidden in the logs after. So the values actually passed to my console app gets the correct values but they are then hidden again when i write then out to the log once again.

A small manipulation of the input argument strings and printing those indicated this.